# How can I read lines from a file into an array that are not comments or empty?

Tags: ruby

I have a text file where a line may be either blank, a comment (begins with `//`) or an instruction (i.e. anything **not** blank or a comment). For instance:

```
Hiya #{prefs("interlocutor")}!

// Say morning appropriately or hi otherwise
#{(0..11).include?(Time.now.hour) ? 'Morning' : 'Hi'} #{prefs("interlocutor")}
```

I'm trying to read the contents of the file into an array where only the instruction lines are included (i.e. skip the blank lines and comments). I have this code (which works):

```
path = Pathname.new("test.txt")
# Get each line from the file and reject comment lines
lines = path.readlines.reject{ |line| line.start_with?("//") }.map{ |line| line.chomp }
# Reject blank lines
lines = lines.reject{ |line| line.length == 0 }
```

Is there a more efficient or elegant way of doing it?

Comment: Ruby doesn't use `//` for comments, it uses `#`, but the problem is that `#` also appears inside strings as an interpolation indicator, not a comment.

Comment: @tadman: Yeah I know. The instructions in the file are run through `eval()` so might include `#` at the beginning of the line. Chose to use `//` to indicate a comment.

Comment: It's not clear what the end goal is here, nor why you need this peculiar form in the first place. Maybe you can better describe your intent and how `//` might appear. If it's in a string do you ignore it? Is it presumed that `//` can be in the middle of a line? If so, `line.sub(%r[//.*], '')` can delete the comment and everything after, then you can `lines.reject(&:empty?)`.

Answer (score 2):

`start_with` takes multiple arguments, so you can do

```
File.open("test.txt").each_line.reject{|line| line.start_with?("//", "\n")}.map(&:chomp)
```

in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so, using regex:

```
def read_commands(path)
  File.read(path).split("\n").reduce([]) do |results, line|
    case line
    when /^\s*\/\/.*$/ # check for comments
    when /^\s*$/       # check for empty lines
    else
      results.push line
    end
    results
  end
end
```

To break down the regexes:

```
comments_regex = %r{
  ^     # beginning of line
  \s*   # any number of whitespaces
  \/\/  # the // sequence
  .*    # any number of anything
  $     # end of line
}x

empty_lines_regex = %r{
  ^     # beginning of line
  \s*   # any number of whitespaces
  $     # end of line
}x
```

Comment: The regex `/^\s*\/\/.*$/` is redundant. You only need `/^\s*\/\//`. But to my interpretation, it should rather be `/^\/\//`.